# If $\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \ge 1 -\frac {1}{n} -\frac {1}{n^2}$ then $\sum\limits_na_n$ diverges

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Let $(a_n)_{n \ge 1}$ be a sequence of positive real numbers such that, for every $n\ge1$,
>   $$\frac {a_{n+1}}{a_n} \ge 1 -\frac {1}{n}  -\frac {1}{n^2} \tag 2$$ Prove that $x_n=a_1 + a_2 + .. + a_n$ diverges.

It is clear that $x_n$ is increasing, so it has to have a limit. I tried to prove the limit is $+\infty$ but without success. No divergence criteria from series seems to work here.

**UPDATE**

Attempt: 
Suppose a stronger inequality holds, namely that, for every $n\ge1$, $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geqslant1-\frac1n \tag 1$$ Then:
$$\frac {a_3}{a_2} \ge \frac 1 2\qquad
\frac {a_4}{a_3} \ge \frac 2 3\qquad
\ldots\qquad
\frac {a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \ge \frac {n-3}{n-2}\qquad
\frac {a_n}{a_{n-1}} \ge \frac {n-2}{n-1}$$
Multiplying all the above yields
$$\frac {a_n}{a_2} \ge \frac 1 {n-1}$$
The last inequality proves the divergence.

Comment: Have you tried [Gauss's test](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/GausssTest.html)?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt This would simply be taking the result for granted, no?

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt Gauss's test solves the problem for sure, but I would like something rather elementary.

Comment: @Did :-) I suppose so, but if its got a name, you can google the proof. For example, I found [this one](http://www.stumblingrobot.com/2016/03/10/prove-gauss-test-convergence-series-positive-terms/) rather easily.

Comment: @EugenCovaci that is a contradiction to your statement "No divergence criteria work here": Gauss works. End of Proof.

Comment: The **idea** of the proof of Gauss's test is not so complicated, and rather illuminating, I would say. To get to it, how would you prove that $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geqslant1-\frac1n$$ implies divergence?

Comment: @Did Writing the inequality for $n=1, 2 ... n$ then multiplying all the resulting inequalities might work.

Comment: Please be more precise (as you guessed, we will adapt the method to your case so we have to know exactly the method in this simpler case).

Comment: @MarcusMüller That's nitpicking. The OP obviously meant "none of the most standard (and well-known, widely taught) divergence criteria work here." Otherwise, you can always have one *ad hoc* divergence criterion per series, and invoke it.

Comment: Hm, Gauss was one of the convergence criteria for sums I was told in engineering first semester, so I was presuming that it's rather well-known. It's also really easy to remember and motivate, imho,

Comment: @Did I updated my answer. The problem is (1) is stronger than what I have.

Comment: Excellent. So, you consider $$b_n=\frac1{n-1}$$ then you note that $$\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}\leqslant1-\frac1n$$ hence $$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geqslant\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$$ hence $$a_n\geqslant Cb_n$$ for some irrelevant but positive value of $C$ and since $\sum b_n$ diverges, you are done. To adapt this strategy to your case, you merely have to find $(c_n)$ such that $\sum c_n$ diverges and $$\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\leqslant1-\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}$$ Any idea?

Comment: @Did From (2) doesn't follow $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\geqslant\frac{b_{n+1}}{b_n}$

Comment: ?? Of course, which is why the sequence $(b_n)$ solving the simpler case $1-\frac1n$ should be replaced by another sequence $(c_n)$ if one wants to solve the case $1-\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}$.

Comment: @EugenCovaci Not sure what you mean, but here Did refers to the "simpler" case where you assume $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq 1-\frac{1}{n}$. The idea is to abstract what works in that case, and generalize it to the (tougher, but similar) situation you have.

Comment: Thanks, @ClementC.

Comment: @Did I've got the idea, but I cannot find $c_n$

Comment: Try something of the form $c_n = \frac{1}{n}+\frac{A}{n^2}$, for some parameter $A$ (this may not be the most elegant).

Comment: " I've got the idea" Perfect (IMHO, this is by far the most important point). Re $c_n$, did you try some simple form, say $$c_n=\frac1{n+\alpha}$$ for some well chosen value of $\alpha$? When yu will have found $(c_n)$, I suggest that you collect the proof and post it as an answer below.

Comment: @Clement C. I beg to differ. That the Gauss test is not "well known and widely taught", is a failure of mathematical education, in the West. In standard text books in Russia (_not_ lost in translation in surprisingly many countries in the East), Gauss test _is_ taught, and rightly so. It would save us from all those annoying "ratio test is inconclusive" questions at MSE, btw.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Right, but the OP was not exposed to this literature, obviously, so we can take this as an opportunity to actually do some maths on this page (something that happens too rarely on MSE), don't you think? You noticed that "doing some maths" neither refers to mentioning that one already knows the result hence there is nothing to prove, nor to "magic" inequalities provided without explanation and yielding the result.

Comment: @ProfessorVector Sure, and I agree this ought to be taught (I was taught some variant of it in France, and don't regret it). And so? Unless you have a plan to retroactively change the "mathematical education [system] in the West," this is not really going to help the OP or anyone in the next 10 years or so. Plus, as Did points out... sometimes, getting intuition and *proving* things from scratch may be a good idea, instead of directly using a sledgehammer.

Comment: @EugenCovaci You think so? Please explain why.

Comment: It doesn't satisfy: $\frac{c_{n+1}}{c_n}\leqslant1-\frac1n-\frac1{n^2}$

Comment: @EugenCovaci $\alpha$ can be negative.

Comment: Eugen: You do not "explain" much, sorry to say... Fortunately, @ClementC. has mind-reading abilities. :-)

Comment: This case works, for let's say $\alpha = -2$

Comment: *Ottimo!* Now, wrap up everything we said and concoct an answer based on it... :-)

Comment: @Did Hey man, I'm a Java programmer trying to help a kid with some math problems. Why are you torturing me?

Comment: Because for some of us, actually doing some mathematics is **not** a torture. And because a part of the ethos of mathematicians is to be convinced that the whole world, if put in a suitable situation, can do maths and take pleasure from the activity. Yes, optimism... (Will you write an answer?)

Comment: @Did Yes, I'll write it

Comment: *Überkewl*. :-)

Comment: @Did The answer is bellow, thank you.

Comment: Nice post. And, just to be clear: it is perfectly allowed to accept one's own answer.

Comment: @Did Actually it's your answer more than mine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may notice that
$$ \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \geq \left(1-\frac{1}{n}\right)\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}\right)^{-1} \tag{1}$$
hence:
$$ \frac{a_{N+1}}{a_2}\geq \frac{1}{N}\prod_{n=2}^{N}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}\right)^{-1} \tag{2}$$
but the infinite product $\prod_{n\geq 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}\right)^{-1}$ is convergent to a positive number ($-\frac{1}{\pi}\cos\frac{\sqrt{5}}{2}\approx 0.296675134743591$). It follows that $a_{N+1}\geq \frac{C}{N}$ so $\sum_{n\geq 2}a_n$ is divergent.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain his/her downvote?

Comment: Very unique answer. +1 the evaluation of infinite product in closed form is another gem.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Do they ever?

Comment: @ClementC.: it happened once or twice. I have no problem in fixing wrong or not-so-clear parts and I think it does not hurt to request an explanation nicely.

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio I agree, my comment was more of a fatalistic flavor. Downvoters often don't care much about hanging around long enough to explain the rationale, if any.

Comment: Nice answer, but can you prove $\prod_{n=2}^{\infty}\left(1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}\right)^{-1}$ is convergent (or bounded it's enough)?

Comment: @EugenCovaci By comparison, if you don't care about the value. From $$\ln \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}}= \ln\left(1-\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right) = -\frac{1}{n^2}+o\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ you get $$\ln \prod_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}} = \sum_{n=2}^N \ln \frac{1}{1+\frac{1}{n^2-n-1}}$$ which, by comparison, has same convergence nature as $-\sum_{n=2}^N \frac{1}{n^2}$, itself convergent. So the logarithm of the infinite product converges to a finite value: the infinite product itself then does so as well (and the limit is positive).

Comment: (But knowing Jack D'Aurizio, there is a neat and clever way to get the convergence *and* the actual limiting value at once.)

Comment: @EugenCovaci: by exploiting a well-known lemma - If $\prod_{n\geq 2}(1+b_n)$ is an infinite product with $b_n>0$ and $\sum_{n\geq 2}b_n$ converges, then the infinite product is convergent to a positive number.

Answer (score 4):

It's easy to show that, for every $n\ge3$, 
$$ 1 -\frac {1}{n}  -\frac {1}{n^2}
  \ge \frac {n-2}{n-1}$$ It follows that, for every $n\ge3$, 
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\ge \frac {n-2}{n-1}$$
Thus,
$$\frac {a_4}{a_3} \ge \frac 1 2\qquad
\frac {a_5}{a_4} \ge \frac 2 3\qquad
\ldots\qquad
\frac {a_{n-1}}{a_{n-2}} \ge \frac {n-4}{n-3}\qquad
\frac {a_n}{a_{n-1}} \ge \frac {n-3}{n-2}$$

Multiplying all the above, one gets:
$$\frac {a_n}{a_3} \ge \frac 1 {n-2}$$
hence $$a_n\ge \frac{a_3}{n-2}$$
The last inequality together with the comparison criteria for series proves the divergence.